# SignalR hub hangs on IIS

Tags: asp.net, signalr

We use SignalR library in our ASP.NET web application. The code looks as following:

Server:

```
[HubName("ticketsCounterHub")]
public class MassivePrintHub : Hub
{
    public void PostTicketsCount(long count)
    {
        Clients.All.Send(count);
    }
}

public class HubFactory
{
    private HubFactory() {}

    public static readonly HubFactory Current = new HubFactory();

    public IHubProxy GetMassivePrintHubProxy()
    {
        var hubConnection = new HubConnection(ConfigUtils.GetRequiredSettingValue("adminPath"));
        var hubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("ticketsCounterHub");
        hubConnection.Start().Wait();
        return hubProxy;
    }
}
```

Client (JavaScript):

```
MassivePrintApp.controller("ListController", function ($scope, Dates) {
    var hubManager = (function () {
        var massivePrintHub = $.connection.ticketsCounterHub;
        $.connection.hub.start();
        return { massivePrintHub: massivePrintHub };
    } ());

    hubManager.massivePrintHub.client.Send = function (ticketsCount) {
        $scope.action.Quantity = ticketsCount;
        $scope.$digest();
    };
});
```

The key part of code is in MVC controller:

```
public FileResult PrintAction(int actionId, int count, DateTime actionDate, bool isThermo=false)
{
    var ticketsCount = _ticketService.GetTicketsInStatusCount(actionId, actionDate, TicketStatusEnum.ToPrint);

    HubFactory.Current.GetMassivePrintHubProxy().Invoke("PostTicketsCount", ticketsCount);

    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    xmlResponse.Save(stream);
    stream.Flush();
    stream.Position = 0;
    return File(stream,ContentTypeEnum.XML.ToString(),String.Format("массовая {0} мероприятия {1} {2}шт.xml", isThermo?"термопечать":"печать", action.Artist,count));
}
```

As you can see, we have this line:

```
HubFactory.Current.GetMassivePrintHubProxy().Invoke("PostTicketsCount", ticketsCount);
```

And that causes the issue, that is whenever we call it one more instance of hub was added to "Requests" section on IIS.

I understand we already started hub in JavaScript code, but I'm not sure how can I use the existing connection or how to get rid of HubFactory or delete created hub instance.

And I don't understand why hub hangs on IIS.

Comment: Is the Hub class in a different application as your MVC controller? If no, then instead of creating a hubproxy, you could call through hub context like here: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#callfromoutsidehub

Comment: MVC controller is placed in dependent project that main ASP.NET application uses. I've already tried to use hub context in this way:

    IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MassivePrintHub>();
    context.Clients.All.Send(ticketsCount);

But, it doesn't work. Maybe I did something wrong.

Comment: Hub is placed in another project as well.

Comment: Aren't you deadlocking yourself here: `hubConnection.Start().Wait();`?

Comment: What should be written? If you write: hubConnection.Start(); There's error message: {"ErrorMessage":"The connection has not been established.","ErrorCode":1001}

Comment: We use .NET Framework 4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from a more simple example will help you a lot I guess. After that you can look into hosting your SignalR server differently (Console App or Windows Service) the basics won't change

(First installed SignalR: NuGet: `install-package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR`)

I made a simple web-app example. The project has a Hub class:

```c#
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace SRTest
{
    public class MassivePrintHub : Hub
    {
        private static IHubContext hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MassivePrintHub>();

        // Can be called from your Javascript code
        public void PostTicketsCount(long count)
        {
            Clients.All.Send(count);
        }

        // Can be called from your c# code
        public static void Static_PostTicketsCount(long count)
        {
            hubContext.Clients.All.Send(count);
        }
    }
}
```

An Owin startup class:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(SRTest.Startup))]
namespace SRTest
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration();
            hubConfiguration.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
            app.MapSignalR(hubConfiguration);
        }
    }
}
```

Page (Razor just to be able to call a simulator which calls a c# class to post message from backend):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>TEST PAGE</title>

    <!--Reference the jQuery library. -->
    <script src='Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js'></script>
    <!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
    <script src='Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js'></script>
    <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
    <script src="signalr/hubs"></script>

</head>
<body>

    THIS IS A TEST PAGE
    <!-- Call simulator (trigger event every 5 seconds) -->
    @{SRTest.SendFromBackEnd.SimulateSend();}

<script>
    $(function () {
        var printHub = $.connection.massivePrintHub;

        // when send event happens
        printHub.client.send = function (count) {
            console.log("Send " + count + " tickets");
        };

        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            console.log("Connected");
        });

        $.connection.hub.logging = true;
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And I added a dummy class which triggers the event through hubcontext every 5 seconds.

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Web;

namespace SRTest
{
    public class SendFromBackEnd
    {
        public static void SimulateSend()
        {
            new Thread(() =>
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;
                while (true)
                {
                    MassivePrintHub.Static_PostTicketsCount(2);
                    Thread.Sleep(5000);
                }
            }).Start();

        }
    }
}
```

I added some loggings to the SignalR, add some debug points, it will help you understand the basics, then it will be much easier to build what you are planning to build.

**EDIT**

About the hanging request: As long as you have a client connected to your SignalR server with SSE or AJAX Long-Polling, you will have an ongoing request, which never finishes. (In case of AJAX Long-polling, it finishes for very short times and comes back). In the apps where I use only Javascript clients, I only see the request if a page is open where I am listening to events. If no page or static page open then no request.
In the apps where I am using .NET clients, as long as the two apps are running, and both Sartup classes executed, the request will always be there, even if no page open. (Since the .NET client is still listening to events.)

For more info: http://hanselminutes.com/291/damian-edwards-explains-the-realtime-web-for-aspnet-with-signalr

Comment: I've commented out Invoke call in my MVC controller, and tried to use your static call, but it doesn't work and SIgnalR request still hangs on IIS. With Invoke everything works fine, but SIgnalR request still hangs on IIS. My goal is to get rid of hanging request. Why is it hanging?

Comment: What is the client protocol?

Comment: Actually, the call of MVC controller's method is done from main ASP.NET application in this way:

    <a class="btn btn-mini" ng-href="/Resources/MassivePrint/PrintAction?actionId={{action.ActionID}}&actionDate={{action.ActionDate}}&count={{count}}&isThermo=false" target="_blank">Get file</a>

MVC controller is placed in separate DLL.

I'm not sure if this affects on issue.

Comment: If you enable in JS `$.connection.hub.logging = true;` You will see the negotiation steps.

Comment: Or when you view the requests, you will see `yourApp/signalr/...clientProtocol=1.4&transport=serverSentEvents`...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81364/discussion-between-tesicg-and-ddan).

Comment: Is there something about cross-domain stuff?

Comment: I've taken a look in "Request" panel on IIS in order to see what the client protocol is, but there's no clientProtocol there. There's transport=serverSentEvent... only.

Comment: So it's SSE. I believe SSE will have a long Request to start communication, then whenever there is info the server sends back, but the communication is still going on. Pretty much like AJAX long polling.
Better explanation here by Damian Edwards, one of the creators of SignalR: http://s3.amazonaws.com/hanselminutes/hanselminutes_0291.pdf

Comment: That's the trascript of this podcast, where Damian Edwards explains the basics of how SingalR works. I hope it helps.

Comment: As long as you have a client listening to your server events, you will have an open request there.

Comment: You mean on browser as a client?

Comment: The hanging request was killed only after rebuilding the project that is after restarting IIS.

Comment: If looking in Chrome at Network tab, there is an ongoing never finished request. I can see the request in IIS Requests as well.

Comment: So, that's the issue and I can't get rid of that request.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts to help. It seems I can't get rid of those requests until restarting IIS.

Comment: Your HubFactory class creates that request, and actually it will never stop, because it makes your server to be it;s own client. So it will always keep a connection open to itself. Hub defines the server, and your HubConnection class will be the client.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Threading related issue. Try like this

```
Task.Run(() => connection.Start().ContinueWith(task =>
            {

                 .....

            })).Wait();
```

Comment: This had zero upvotes so I was skeptical -> but for me, I did not need this when starting the connection in a simple console app -> but when I tried to replicate the connection in a WPF app, starting the connection on the main thread caused it to hang on "Connecting". Threading it out like this solved the problem. Nice!